# How to remove similar folder from multiple locations in terminal

Tags: terminal

I have a folder 'reg_standard' nested within 68 different folders that I want to remove. The path to this folder looks something like:

```
/Volumes/.../sub-???/run_?.feat/reg_standard
```

How can I remove this folder and all its contents efficiently? Do I use rm -r?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "terminal"?

Answer (score 0):

I propose using regex:

```bash
find "/Volumes/**/sub-\d\d\d/run_\d\.feat/reg_standard" -delete
```

Comment: I will update the answer when the character `?` is defined.

Comment: Hi @Ci Leong, thanks for helping! '?' is a stand-in for all the different folders that start with 'sub' or 'run'. For example, I have sub-101, sub-102, sub-162 (34 in total) and run_1 and run_2 folders nested within each sub-???, making a total of 68 folders in total where reg_standard exists

Comment: I have updated my answer. I am finding and deleting `sub-ddd/run_d.feat/reg_standard` any depth under `/Volumes`, where `d` represents a single digit [0-9].